# Why is this always returning False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this always returning `"box1 won't fit in box2"`. `def canBox1FitInBox2` always returns `false` even if it's not... What am I missing?

Even if the input is `box1 = 1,1,1` and `box2 = 10,10,10`.

This is an exercise, I know there are probably a lot of better ways to do this but I need it to be done like this:

```
class Box:
    length = 0
    width = 0
    height = 0

    # This method will check the length, width, & height
    # then it will output which dimension is the longest
    def getLongestSide(self):
        self.max = self.length
        if self.width > self.max:
            self.max = self.width
        if self.height > self.max:
            self.max = self.height
        return self.max

    (This I Wrote)\
    # This method should output which dimension is the shortest
    def getShortestSide(self):
        self.min = self.length
        if self.width < self.min:
            self.min = self.width
        if self.height < self.min:
            self.min = self.height
        return self.min
        # TODO: Finish this method (^This I Wrote)\
```

---

```
from Box import Box


box1 = Box()
dimensions1 = input("Enter box1's dimensions ex. 1 2 3").split()
box1.length = int(dimensions1[0])
box1.width = int(dimensions1[1])
box1.height = int(dimensions1[2])

box2 = Box()
dimensions2 = input("Enter box2's dimensions ex. 1 2 3").split()
box2.length = int(dimensions2[0])
box2.width = int(dimensions2[1])
box2.height = int(dimensions2[2])

(This I Wrote)\
def canBox1FitInBox2(box1, box2):
    if box1.getLongestSide() <= box2.getShortestSide():
         return canBox1FitInBox2 == True
    else:
         return canBox1FitInBox2 == False
(This I Wrote)\
#TODO: Use the getLongestSide and getShortestSide methods in the Box Class to determine
if box1 will fit in box2 then return true or false.

#Hint: if the longest dimension of box1 is smaller than the shortest dimension of
box2, then box1 fits in box2


if canBox1FitInBox2(box1, box2) == True:
    print("box1 will fit in box2")
else:
    print("box1 wont fit in box2")
```

Comment: Start by defining `Box.__init__` to properly initialize the three attributes of a box when the box is created. Don't define `length` et al. as *class* attributes.

Comment: `return canBox1FitInBox2 == True` is comparing a *function* to a boolean value.  `False` is the only conceivable result, you probably just want `return True` there.  But your logic is broken anyway - `box1.getLongestSide() <= box2.getShortestSide()` certainly means that box1 will fit inside box2, but there are other conditions where that would be true (you'd just need to have a specific orientation between the two boxes).

Comment: I only wrote 2 parts of the code (edited and mentioned where).
This is a beginner exercise... this is how they want me to get the result it is described as a comments (they wrote the comments).

@jasonharper changing it to return True, fixed it.
Not sure how to flag your comment as the answer :/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the function canBox1FitInBox2 is returning values after comparing the function called again canBox1FitInBox2 without arguments, with True and False using the comparison operator(==)

Thus, calling the function without argument is throwing some garbage value and it is being compared with True and False, and thus function is returning always False.

Simply do this:

```
if box1.getLongestSide() <= box2.getShortestSide():
     return True
else:
     return False
```

and your code will run fine.

Comment: Note that those four lines could be merged into one: `return box1.getLongestSide() <= box2.getShortestSide()`.